# How can I get the html tags from an input rather than the text?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that takes input and then outputs the HTML tags. Although I've managed to do the opposite.

```
import re

text = '<p>I want this bit removed</p>'
tags = re.search('>(.*)<', text)

print(tags.group(1))
```

At the moment, if I run this, it removes the HTML tags and keeps the text. But I want it so that the output is `['p','/p']`. How can I do this? I also want to make it so that it can adapt to any input.

Also, if possible, I'd like to adapt this to a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the regex to look for the text inside the `<` `>` instead.

```py
import re

text = '<p>I want this bit removed</p>'
tags = re.findall('<([^>]*)>', text) # [^>] means anything except a `>`

print(tags) # tags is an iterable object (basically a list) here
```